# Generating Multiple basemap plots from NetCDF using loop

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap

I need to generate multiple plots of geopotential height anomalies (data taken from NCEP NCAR reanalysis), for which I use python netCDF4 and basemap package. The code I wrote generates single image, but would like to modify it to produce multiple plots. The code for generating a single image is given below:

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset, num2date
import os
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
C=Dataset('G:\\GPANC\\hgt.2010.nc','r')
C3=C.variables['hgt'][177,2,:,:]
C1=C.variables['time']
dates = num2date(C1[:], C1.units)
dates[177:180]
X1 = [1970,1971,1973,1974,1975,1977,1978,1979,1981,1982,1983,1985,1986,1987,1989,1990,1991,1993,1994,1995,1997,1998,1999,2001,2002,2003,2005,2006,2007,2009,2010,2011,2013,2014,2015,2017,2018]
X2 = [1972,1976,1980,1984,1988,1992,1996,2000,2004,2008,2012,2016]
Z1=np.zeros([37,73,144])
row11=0
Z2=np.zeros([12,73,144])
row12=0
for year in X1:
  N1=Dataset('G:\\GPANC\\hgt.'+str(year)+'.nc','r')
  Z1[row11,:,:]=N1.variables['hgt'][177,2,:,:]
  row11=row11+1
  print(year)
for year in X2:
  N2=Dataset('G:\\GPANC\\hgt.'+str(year)+'.nc','r')
  Z2[row12,:,:]=N2.variables['hgt'][178,2,:,:]
  row12=row12+1
  print(year)
y=np.concatenate((Z1,Z2))
b1=N1.variables['lon'][:]
c1=N1.variables['lat'][:]
z=np.mean(y, axis=0)
S=C3-z
plt.subplot(111)
map = Basemap(projection='cyl',llcrnrlat= 4,urcrnrlat= 50,\
                 resolution='h', llcrnrlon=45,urcrnrlon=125)
map.drawparallels(np.arange(4,50,6),labels=[1,0,0,0],linewidth=0,fontsize=8)
map.drawmeridians(np.arange(45,125,8),labels=[0,0,0,1],linewidth=0,fontsize=8)
map.drawcountries(linewidth=1.5)
map.drawcoastlines(linewidth=1.5)
df=[{'lon': 80.3319, 'lat': 26.4499,'site':'Kanpur'}]
for point in df:
    u,v=map(point['lon'],point['lat'])
    plt.plot(u,v,marker='o',color='red',ms=5)
    plt.annotate(point['site'], xy=(u,v),  xycoords='data',xytext=(-8,3), textcoords = 'offset points')
x6,y6=np.meshgrid(b1,c1)
q6,p6=map(x6,y6)
CI=[-80,-72,-64,-56,-48,-40,-32,-24,-16,-8,0,8,16,24,32,40,48,56,64]
map.contourf(q6,p6,S,CI,cmap='gist_ncar',extend='both',zorder=1)
clb=plt.colorbar()
clb.set_label('m', labelpad=-40, y=1.05, rotation=0)
clb.set_ticks([-80,-72,-64,-56,-48,-40,-32,-24,-16,-8,0,8,16,24,32,40,48,56,64])
Z6=plt.contour(q6,p6,S,CI,colors='black',linewidths=1,zorder=2)
plt.clabel(Z6, inline=1, fontsize=8,fmt="%i")
plt.title('Geopotential height Anomalies (850 hPa) on 27-06-2010 (1970-2018 Climatology)',fontsize=10,pad=10)

#in order to develop multiple plots I made following changes
data=[]
for i in np.arange(177,180,1):
                C3=C.variables['hgt'][i,2,:,:]
                data.append(C3)
X1 = [1970,1971,1973,1974,1975,1977,1978,1979,1981,1982,1983,1985,1986,1987,1989,1990,1991,1993,1994,1995,1997,1998,1999,2001,2002,2003,2005,2006,2007,2009,2010,2011,2013,2014,2015,2017,2018]
X2 = [1972,1976,1980,1984,1988,1992,1996,2000,2004,2008,2012,2016]
Z1=np.zeros([37,73,144])
row11=0
Z2=np.zeros([12,73,144])
row12=0
for year in X1: 
               for i in np.arange(177,180,1):
                      N1=Dataset('G:\\GPANC\\hgt.'+str(year)+'.nc','r')
                      Z1[row11,:,:]=N1.variables['hgt'][i,2,:,:]
                      row11=row11+1
                      print(year)    # I get an error here
1970
1970
1970
1971
1971
1971
1973
1973
1973
1974
1974
1974
1975
1975
1975
1977
1977
1977
1978
1978
1978
1979
1979
1979
1981
1981
1981
1982
1982
1982
1983
1983
1983
1985
1985
1985
1986
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
IndexError: index 37 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 37
```

I have 2 questions here
1. How to store data from multiple NetCDF files for the dates 177 to 180 and
2. How to use the stored data in generating multiple basemap plots i.e., for all the dates from 177 to 180 [date 177 represents 27-06-2010 and so on]

Answer (score 0):

Here's a reference that might be useful though it uses xarray and cartopy instead of basemap from Matplotlib.

https://unidata.github.io/MetPy/latest/examples/Four_Panel_Map.html

Xarray is very useful when dealing with multidimensional data. You can easily select the values within a given time range using sel and slice functions.

you can learn more about it here:
http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/time-series.html

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Dani56 for the necessary links, I was able to generate the plots. The code for generating multiple Geo-potential height anomaly plots is given below:

```
#loading required packages
from netCDF4 import Dataset, num2date
import os
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

C=Dataset('G:\\GPANC\\hgt.1977.nc','r')
data=[]
for i in np.arange(288,291,1):
                 C3=C.variables['hgt'][i,2,:,:]
                 data.append(C3)

X1 = [1970,1971,1973,1974,1975,1977,1978,1979,1981,1982,1983,1985,1986,1987,1989,1990,1991,1993,1994,1995,1997,1998,1999,2001,2002,2003,2005,2006,2007,2009,2010,2011,2013,2014,2015,2017,2018]
X2 = [1972,1976,1980,1984,1988,1992,1996,2000,2004,2008,2012,2016]

Z1=[]
for year in X1: 
            N1=Dataset('G:\\GPANC\\hgt.'+str(year)+'.nc','r')
            for i in np.arange(288,291,1):
                                    K1=N1.variables['hgt'][i,2,:,:]
                                    Z1.append(K1)
                                    print(year) 
Z2=[]
for year in X2: 
            N2=Dataset('G:\\GPANC\\hgt.'+str(year)+'.nc','r')
            for i in np.arange(289,292,1):
                                    K2=N2.variables['hgt'][i,2,:,:]
                                    Z2.append(K2)
                                    print(year) 
#non-leap year
P1 = [Z1[i] for i in np.arange(0,111,3)]
P2 = [Z1[i] for i in np.arange(1,111,3)]
P3 = [Z1[i] for i in np.arange(2,111,3)]

#leap year
Q1 = [Z2[i] for i in np.arange(0,36,3)]
Q2 = [Z2[i] for i in np.arange(1,36,3)]
Q3 = [Z2[i] for i in np.arange(2,36,3)]

#Concatenating the leap and non-leap year data
Y1=np.concatenate((P1,Q1))
Y2=np.concatenate((P2,Q2))
Y3=np.concatenate((P3,Q3))

#Anomaly
ANA1=data[0]-np.mean(Y1, axis=0)
ANA2=data[1]-np.mean(Y2, axis=0)
ANA3=data[2]-np.mean(Y3, axis=0)

#plotting with Basemap
#Coordinates of Thiruvananthapuram
lat = 8.5241
lon =76.9366
def plot_background(ax):
                  map = Basemap(projection='cyl',ax=ax,llcrnrlat= 4,urcrnrlat= 50,\
                                                resolution='h', llcrnrlon=45,urcrnrlon=125)
                  map.drawparallels(np.arange(4,50,6),labels=[1,0,0,0],linewidth=0,fontsize=8)
                  map.drawmeridians(np.arange(45,125,8),labels=[0,0,0,1],linewidth=0,fontsize=8)
                  map.drawcoastlines(linewidth=1.5)
                  map.drawcountries(linewidth=1.5)
                  lons, lats = map(lon, lat)
                  map.scatter(lons, lats, marker = 'o', s = 15, color='r')
                  return ax

fig=plt.figure() #figsize=(a,b) may be passed into this
ax1 = plt.subplot(221)
ax2 = plt.subplot(222)
ax3 = plt.subplot(223)
axlist = [ax1,ax2,ax3]
for ax in axlist:
                plot_background(ax)

b1=C.variables['lon'][:]
c1=C.variables['lat'][:]
x,y=np.meshgrid(b1,c1)
CI=[-80,-72,-64,-56,-48,-40,-32,-24,-16,-8,0,8,16,24,32,40,48,56,64]

A = axlist[0].contourf(x,y,ANA1,CI,cmap='gist_ncar',extend='both',zorder=1)
A1 = axlist[0].contour(x,y,ANA1,CI,colors='black',linewidths=1,zorder=2)
axlist[0].clabel(A1, inline=1, fontsize=8,fmt="%i")
axlist[0].set_title('16-10-1977',fontsize=10,pad=10)

B = axlist[1].contourf(x,y,ANA2,CI,cmap='gist_ncar',extend='both',zorder=1)
B1 = axlist[1].contour(x,y,ANA2,CI,colors='black',linewidths=1,zorder=2)
axlist[1].clabel(B1, inline=1, fontsize=8,fmt="%i")
axlist[1].set_title('17-10-1977',fontsize=10,pad=10)

D = axlist[2].contourf(x,y,ANA3,CI,cmap='gist_ncar',extend='both',zorder=1)
D1 = axlist[2].contour(x,y,ANA3,CI,colors='black',linewidths=1,zorder=2)
axlist[2].clabel(D1, inline=1, fontsize=8,fmt="%i")
axlist[2].set_title('18-10-1977',fontsize=10,pad=10)

Z=plt.colorbar(A, ax=[ax1,ax2,ax3],shrink=0.8, aspect=20, fraction=.15,pad=.05)
Z.set_ticks([-80,-72,-64,-56,-48,-40,-32,-24,-16,-8,0,8,16,24,32,40,48,56,64])
Z.set_label('m', labelpad=-40, y=1.05, rotation=0)
plt.suptitle('Geopotential height anomalies for given dates at 850 hPa', fontsize=15)
```

[Following image is generated after the code runs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEG0Q.png)